# how to add an edge for two existing nodes/vertexs in jung

Tags: java, jung

can you help me please? how I can add an edge between two nodes/vertexs which those nodes are existed in graph.
my graph use custom vertex and custom edge class.
here my code

```
if(findEdge(g,v1,v2)==null) 
g.addEdge(new Edge(), v1, v2, EdgeType.DIRECTED);
```

where findEdge function is

```
public Edge findEdge(DirectedGraph<Vertex, Edge> g, Vertex v1,Vertex v2) {
    Collection<Edge> edges = g.getEdges();
    for (Edge ed : edges) { 
        //System.out.print(vt.getLabel() + " ");
        if(ed.getNodeFrom().equals(v1.getLabel())&&ed.getNodeDes().equals(v2.getLabel())) {
            return ed;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

from that function, I can get result about two existed nodes's edge, is existed or null.

Comment: You could consider using http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/Hypergraph.html#findEdge%28V,%20V%29 . Apart from that, it's not really clear what the question is.

Comment: I'm sorry about my unclear question. I mean, I have graph DirectedGraph<Vertex,Edge> g = new DirectedSparseMultigraph<Vertex,Edge>() and there are many vertexs/node in that graph, I want to add an edge to existed nodes in that graph g, but I don't know how to do.

Comment: Is that a multigraph? If not, simply call `addEdge()` again, there should be only one edge (I have worked with Jung years before, but IIRC it has not been developed for 4 years or so, but I believe there was such a feature).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Graph already has a findEdge() method; look at the API docs that Marco13@ pointed you to.

Second, as rlegendi@ pointed out, it's not clear whether you want a multigraph or not: if you do, why are you only adding an edge if there isn't one present, and if you don't, why are you creating a DirectedSparseMultigraph object?

It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.